# Automount USB sticks on fedora 22

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, usb-drive, automounting

I need to automount any USB stick that gets connect to any USB port. I am running Fedora 22. I thought this would be straightforward but it is taking a while for me to set up. The tutorial I find when I google it asks me to go to Preferences->Removable Drives And Media, but I don't have that path in my Fedora for some reason.

Comment: This [DOCUMENT](https://linuxconfig.org/automatically-mount-usb-external-drive-with-autofs) explains how it is done from command line if you prefer.

Comment: See if you have it under _Settings > Details > Removable Media_...

Comment: @don_crissti I don't

Comment: Well, I don't use Fedora so can't really help you... they're automounted by default in archlinux fwiw. There's something wrong with your setup as I find it hard to believe they're not automounted in Fedora which is a distro for the masses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that my version of Fedora 22 came without dbux-x11, which is necessary for a message that a USB stick got connected to travel among processes. If anyone has a similar issue, refer to the following document: http://www.techtimejourney.net/solving-the-automount-issue/

Comment: Where did you get Fedora 22? What spin or edition?

Comment: I wasn't the one to get it. The person who did left the job. But it is basically a stripped down version for low memory systems.